# Revenuecat subscriptions with stripe payments

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, revenuecat

is it possible to integrate revenuecat webhook to deal with subscription base on stripe payments.
I had configured webhook from revenuecat and it response 200 when I tried to by product. But I don't see new customer or active subscription in revenuecat overview.
In revenuecat I created new stripe product. I also created new product which has entitlement. It is also included in offerings packages.
Am I doing something wrong or it is just not possible to active subscription with webhook?

Comment: I don't know much about revenuecat, but did you had the chance to check this guide for all Subscription's webhooks and how to track active ones:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#active-subscriptions